# jQuery contains

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to get the deepest element matching a contains statement?

Basicly if I have nested divs, I want the last element not the parent element:

```
<div id="hayStack">
  <div id="needle">Needle</div>
</div>
```

`$("div:contains('Needle')")` is returning the hayStack div.

The only solution I have come up with so far is explicitly exlcuding parent divs by their id with .not

Answer (score 11):

Adding `:last` will return the deepest/last div (the one immedietly encapsulating the content you are searching for

```
$("div:contains('Needle'):last")
```

Comment: I think it would return the last, not the necessarily the deepest.

Comment: Tomalak, since the jQuery engine fallows DOM structure and returns them in the order they are parsed inside the DOM Tree, if the needle has only 1 occurrence on the page, the last element will be the one closest to the needle (deepest inside the DOM Tree)

Comment: This is actually elegant and correct, the :contains selector returns a jQuery array and :last filters out the last one of them, being the closest parent.

Comment: +1 for a great answer... but note this only works if you are looking for a single `Needle`

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div:contains('Needle')").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().size() === 0;
});
```

Gets the list of elements containing 'Needle' then filters out those with any children.

Comment: Why would that be helpful? It may well have children, it should just not have any that contain "needle".

Comment: This will fail if the last div contains any HTML tags like "<br>" or even an <img>

Answer (score 2):

I use this to find the deepest elements when the needle appears multiple times:

```
var needle = 'foo';
var $elms = $('#container').find(':contains('+needle+')').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find(':contains('+needle+')').length === 0;
    });

$elms.addClass('containsfoo');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way that will allow you to find all deepest containers (not only the last one). Just find an element that contains no other jquery elements.

```
$('div:contains("Needle"):not(:has(*))').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I write code to find all deepest element for each leaf.

Main defer this code check deepest by parent, not by child, cause Needle deepest element can contain child too.

http://jsfiddle.net/ncppk0zw/20/

```
var found = $('div:contains("Needle")');

for (var i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
    if (i > 1) {
        if (found[i].parentNode !== found[i-1]) {
            // Deepest. Next element is other leaf
            console.log(found[i-1]);
            continue;
        }
        if (i == found.length-1) {
            // Deepest. Last element in DOM tree
            console.log(found[i]);
        }
    }
}
```