# Select elements with certain content as direct child node

Tags: jquery

I want to select every cell that has a certain text as content. I do it like that:

```
$("td:contains('Some Text')")
```

But in the following mark up that expression finds two `td`s:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Some Text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I only want the cell that actually contains the text, not the cell that contains a table that contains the text in one of its cells.

**How do I modify my selector to get there?**

Comment: try `:last` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765137/jquery-contains

Comment: @evanc3: That would only return one element. But there could be multiple elements with "Some Text" as text in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("td:not(:has(*)):contains('Some Text')")
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MJCCv/)

Comment: Not clear from his example, but what if the td is `<td>Some Text<span>more text</span></td>`

Comment: What was wrong with your original answer? That worked splendidly.

Comment: @Esailija: There is no more mark up inside the desired table cells.

Comment: @Amberlamps `.text() === "Some Text"` only worked accidentally. The other td's `.text()` also *contains* `"Some Text"` but is not strictly equal to `"Some Text"` because it includes the whitespace, whereas the inner `td's` `.text()` is strictly equal because it doesn't have whitespace

Comment: @Esailija: I think that I do not quite understand you. Are you saying that undefined´s provided expression finds cells that contain "Some Text" as well as "Some Text and some more text"?

Comment: @Amberlamps I was referring to the original answer where `.text()` was being used... his current answer works fine because there is not going to be a situation where you have parallel elements next to the target text

Comment: @Esailija The original answer had a problem, because as you are correctly saying if there is whitespace that doesn't return the element.

Comment: @Amberlamps Because my first answer didn't behave like the `:contains()` selector. http://jsfiddle.net/MJCCv/2/

Comment: @Esailija & undefined: About what whitespace are you talking about? There is only one whitespace, the one between `Some` and `Text`. Are you referring to whitespace that exsist between two html tags? If so, I do not see the problem since I do not want those elements in the first place.

Comment: @undefined True and if you do use `.indexOf` you are back to square one: http://jsfiddle.net/MJCCv/3/

Comment: Okay, I understand you know. But my mark up is automatically generated. So there will be no accidental whitespace in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this.childNodes).filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf("Some Text") > -1;
    }).length;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bFUEJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to accomplish this solely by altering the selector, You could always do `$("table table td:contains('Some Text')")`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bFUEJ/

A better alternative would be to give the inner table an ID.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="innerTable">
        <tr>
          <td>Some Text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


//JS
$('#innerTable').find("td:contains('Some Text')");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is way to static. I can not know whether that `td` is always wrapped in two `table`. My mark up was for demonstration purpose only.

Comment: Then you should see my updated response re: adding an ID. In addition, details like that should be posted in the question so we can properly assist you.